# Bring Control to Front when Selected in the Structure Pane

Tags: delphi

I would like to build a Wizard component, where I can guid the user through different pages. When the last page is reached, an action is performed.
That component should work similar as the `TPageControl`, where I can create sheets at design-time. Creating that 'sheets' is already done, but my problem is, that the last added sheet is always on top of the other sheets, and I cannot select another one anymore (which are behind). In the `TPageControl` component, I can select a sheet in the Structure Pane, and it comes to the front, where can I put controls on it.

And this is my question: How can I bring a control (my wizard sheet) to the front, when it is selected in the Structre Pane?

Comment: This is one reason why page controls are often used for this.

Comment: why not use KWizard aka JVCL Wizard ?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution in the KWizard project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to override the `TWinControl.ShowControl` function. That function is fired when you click in the structure pane on the child control. Then, I just need to invoke the `BringToFront` function of that child.